# Android NullPointerException in $Proxy0.equals

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

I've recently published a couple android games based in `libgdx`, both of them have reported an error I have no idea where to begin with debugging. This is the stacktrace.-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null result when primitive expected
at $Proxy0.equals(Native Method)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$g.equals(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.contains(ArrayList.java:342)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dx.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$h.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$h.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$b.bR(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know the problem is something related with Google Play Game Services, but can't figure out what can be causing it. In both cases, the android version seems to be `2.3.3`. Anyone who faced the same issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. I believe is related to the login process, but I don't know where the problem might be... I get something like 100/200 crashes a day on a 10k daily login.

Comment: I think the problem is related with Google Play Services. I have the same issue, but when trying to retrieve an address from a String in Maps.

Comment: Adding information: I also have this problem with android 4.0 and 4.1 versions.

Comment: Thanks so much. Still wondering why an apparently common exception is not documented at all :(

Comment: Hi again! I got a smartphone which throws this error. I attach the error log in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-pBD0UHGxPTN1ZVaEdmNEZ3WE0 so you can also see all the previous log and guess where is the problem. In this case, the app not even runs, it shows directly the "Send Report or Close" dialog.

Comment: I forgot... in the error log, there is also a lot of "W/Trace(17078): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0" messages.

Comment: I don't understand... installing the app by usb works fine! :s

Comment: The timeout maybe has something to do..

Comment: I have the same issue listed in my crashlytics account. I am using google connect... any idea?

Comment: @MaximRahlis wish I had, never found the cause of this issue :(

Comment: Can you please provide the GMS version that throws this exception and stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Try going on properties on your android project , and under the android tag check to see if your google library is there . If it is there try removing it and add it again . 
 This is how i solved this problem and worked for me . (i still get this error sometimes when i start the eclipse ). Good luck !